# Crystal Report pie chart showing same value for onchange despite giving proper chart data settings / options

Tags: graph, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2005, pie-chart

I have a list of categories and their respective counts. OnChange of Category, the count for that respective category must be shown in the Crystal report Pie Chart. It is a simplest pie chart but it shows correct in the preview but not in runtime. At runtime, all the slices of the pie chart are equally divided into the number of categories instead of being proportional to the value of the count column against each category column value of my report dataset table.

I used OnChange of - Category, show values - sum of Count. As that is the generic way of doing this.

I made sure that count is a number in the xsd being used as datasource by the report. But still the pie chart was an equally divided pie at runtime :(

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying, figured out a way to solve this jinx.
Use a formula.
Just declare a number variable. Assign the value of the count column to this variable and then onchange of Category Show values of this formula instead of the column 'count' from xsd.

I created a formula by some name, say MyFormula. Logic in formula as below -

`numbervar nv:= tonumber({MyXSDTable.Count});
nv`

Note - XSDTableName.columnname can be dragged and dropped in the Formula editor. In my case, count column of my XSD was the report field I wanted to make numeric, using this formula.

Now in the Chart Expert, in the Data tab, OnChange of Category, show values of @MyFormula.

Voila problem solved. Pie chart finally recognises the different counts and shows proper proportionate slices instead of showing equally sized slices.

(Previously, though the slices were equal to the no of categories I had in my report details rows, the slice i.e. quadrants size in the pie chart was not reflecting the count value against each category. But after using formula and reassigning value of count to a numeric variable, the pie chart works fine.)

> I think I should give credit to [this](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/message/9825309#9825309) unrelated discussion I found on SAP Crystal Report Forum. Got a clue from there and I used part of their solution to solve my problem. :)